# Why chrome devtools only show failed request instead of 400, 500, or 401?

Tags: google-chrome, http

I'm using latest chrome at the moment (chrome 81), but in chrome dev tool catch http request and only show (failed) on request failed. I tested in Firefox with same case and received status code is 500.

Anyone has idea to show specific status code in chrome again (In chrome version < 70 the status code show in normal, like Firefox)?

[image: Status code in Chrome]

[image: Status code in Firefox]

Thanks!